# Twig display function

Tags: php, twig

I cant quite get a hold of Twig really. I want to just simply display a function in a twig file but nothing is shown. My function:

```
public function ratings(){
        $overall_vote_rows = $blog_vote_overall_rows;
        $overall_vote_rate = $blog_vote_overall_rate;
        $overall_vote_dec_rate = $blog_vote_overall_dec_rate;
        $ip_vote_rate = $blog_vote_ip_rate;

    echo '<input type="hidden" name="blog_content_id" id="blog_content_id" value="1"/>';
                $stars = '';
                echo '<div id="ajax_vote">';
                for ($i = 1; $i <= floor($overall_vote_rate); $i++) {
                    $stars .= '<div class="star" id="' . $i . '"></div>';
                }
                //THE OVERALL RATING (THE OPAQUE STARS)
                echo '<div class="r"><div class="rating">' . $stars . '</div>';

                //THE TRANSPARENT STARS (OPAQUE STARS WILL COVER AS MANY STARS AS THE RATING REPRESENTS)
                echo '<div class="transparent">
            <div class="star" id="1"></div>
            <div class="star" id="2"></div>
            <div class="star" id="3"></div>
            <div class="star" id="4"></div>
            <div class="star" id="5"></div>
            <div class="votes">(' . $blog_vote_overall_dec_rate . '/5, ' . $overall_vote_rows . ' ' . ($overall_vote_rows > 1 ? ' votes' : ' vote') . ') ' . ($blog_vote_ip_rate > 0 ? '<strong>You rated this: <span style="color:#39C;">' . $blog_vote_ip_rate . '</span></strong>' : '') . '</div>
          </div>
        </div>';
                echo '</div>';      

    $this->twig->display('boat/boat_list.twig',$data);
```

Now when i try to display the function it wont show up. i guess i completly missunderstand the principle as such since even trough reading in the documentation im to simple minded to get it.

```
{{ratings}}
```

shouldnt this do the trick?

Thanks in advance. Id love to just use the php code since i cant figure how to properly translate it into the twig syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use a function for this imho. You just need to create a extra `twig template` which you then can include inside the current `template`

**blog.twig**

```
...
{% include "rating.twig.html" %}
```

**rating.twig.html**

```
<input type="hidden" name="blog_content_id" id="blog_content_id" value="1"/>
<div id="ajax_vote">
    {% set stars = '' %}
    {% for i in 1..overall_vote_rate|round(0, 'floor') %}
        {% set stars = '<div class="star" id="'~i~'"></div>
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="r">
        <div class="rating">{{ stars | raw }}</div>
       //THE TRANSPARENT STARS (OPAQUE STARS WILL COVER AS MANY STARS AS THE RATING REPRESENTS)
       <div class="transparent">
            <div class="star" id="1"></div>
            <div class="star" id="2"></div>
            <div class="star" id="3"></div>
            <div class="star" id="4"></div>
            <div class="star" id="5"></div>
            <div class="votes">
            {{ blog_vote_overall_dec_rate }}/5 {{ overall_vote_rows }} {{ overall_vote_rows > 1 ? ' votes' : ' vote' }}
            {% if blog_vote_ip_rate > 0 %}<strong>You rated this: <span style="color:#39C;">{{ blog_vote_ip_rate }} </span></strong>{% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really need to learn the syntax. Right now i get an error in the Line  `{{ blog_vote_overall_dec_rate }}/5 {{ overall_vote_rows }} {{ overall_vote_rows > 1 ? ' votes' : ' vote' }}` because of the ' symbol. What should i change?

Comment: Whats the exact error you're getting? I just created this template without testing. Thats why

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Syntax' with message 'Unexpected character "'" in "boat/rating.twig.html" at line 17.'`

Answer (score 0):

You should register your function like described here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#functions

Something like this:

```
$function = new Twig_SimpleFunction('ratings', function () {
    $html = '<p>Your function content here</p>';    
    $html .= '<input>';
    $html .= '<select></select>';
    // ...
    return $html;
});
$this->twig->addFunction($function);
```

Then in template call your function:

```
{{ ratings()|raw }}
```

Comment: You can avoid using the `raw` filter by returning safe markup with : `return new \Twig_Markup($html, 'UTF-8');`